# teamcity - cannot build maven project package X does not exist

Tags: java, maven, teamcity

I have maven project that has several modules like this:

- parent (empty project, only has pom file)

  - shared
  - web
  - client

I have no problem to build project from IDE and from console locally. To build I use `mvn clean install` from parent directory.
Now I'm trying to configure TeamCity to build project remotely. However I receive compile errors like this:

```
[ERROR] /home/shared/src/main/java/../MyClass.java:[4,34] package com.google.gwt.i18n.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/shared/src/main/java/../MyClass.java:[9,47] cannot find symbol
   symbol: class Messages
```

This is not only about that package, there are several packages that "does not exists", but I can see in logs that all these packages were successfully downloaded from our internal Artifactory.

Parent pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lightoze.gwt-i18n-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-i18n-server</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt-i18n-server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Shared pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightoze.gwt-i18n-server</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-i18n-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post more logs from the maven build (when running on teamcity)? Does it complain for any missing dependencies?

Comment: @Daniele there is not really anything useful there. At first it downloads dependencies (no missing) including that stated missing later, than it says there are compile errors like I posted

Comment: Uhm, still there must be differences between your dev machine and the teamcity server-- can you check the `settings.xml` file (under `$MAVEN_HOME/conf`); maybe there are profiles active by default?

Comment: Another thing, can you run `mvn clean package -U -X > out.log`, and inspect the output? At some point, it will dump something like `[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [C:\..\target\classes, C:\..\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar, ...]` . Can you check if the `jar` file containing the missing `Message` class is really used? And if it is, can you inspect its contents (unzip it) and check that the class is really present. This is to check that the jar is not corrupted

Comment: @Daniele thanks for your suggestions. I've add -X flag and finally understand what was the issue. I've used the same ```settings.xml``` that I use locally. And it contains ```localRepository``` setting which was the cause of this problem

Comment: Great! (it's always the hidden tweak ;p )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in `settings.xml` that I've copied from local machine. It contained local path in `<localRepository>`. After removing it problem gone.